# Google ID login issue on stackoverlfow in the chrome browser after granting the access

Tags: oauth

When logging in stackoverflow.com with my google ID for the first time in the chrome browser, after I clicked on "Allow" button to grant the access, I was not able to login stack overflow at all.

It seems to be Google's OAuth flow problem after granting the access in the chrome browser. This is not only happening on stackoverflow.com, but also happens on other site that allows google ID login, such as dropbox.com, etc.

Did anybody experience the same, and is there any way to bring this to Google's attention to fix it if it's related to the Google OAuth flow?

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.